# Debug window is missing on my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

My debug window is missing on Android Studio. When I clicked on 
View-->Tool Windows , "debug window" is greyed out.

Any input would be appreciated. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfUPy.png)

Comment: Can you add screenshots?

Comment: Hi Edric, I added it. But to be honest I think the text is pretty understandable without showing the screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Connect your device, in the toolbar, click Debug icon or ALT+SHIFT+F9.
Or follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html).

Comment: [Please don't post link only answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Instead state the main points here and use the link mainly as a reference. Links break after a while, making your valuable contribution useless.